# Error while testing BPEL project

Tags: web-services, netbeans, bpel

Running Netbeans 6.5.1 with OpenESB (Glassfish-full-installer-windows2.1).

I'm using this tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a76RxkzB4Bg) as reference to orchestrate web services by calling a local WSDL that invokes an external WSDL (http://www.webservicex.net/CreditCard.asmx?WSDL). I have my BPEL ready

[image]

and my Composite Application created, it automatically binds a SOAP call from my local WSDL to the BPEL (Consumer to Producer), I had to drag and drop another SOAP object and configure it with the same interface as my local WSDL to receive the output from the invoke action (is that correct?).

[image]

When I run my test case selecting the operation from my local WSDL, I get the following SoapResponse:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns="">SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring xmlns="">BPCOR-6135: A fault was not handled in the process scope; Fault Name is {http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling}systemFault; Fault Data is &a....Sending errors for the pending requests in the process scope before terminating the process instance</faultstring>
      <faultactor xmlns="">sun-bpel-engine</faultactor>
      <detail xmlns="">
        <detailText>BPCOR-6135: A fault was not handled in the process scope; Fault Name is {http://www.sun.com/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable/SUNExtension/ErrorHandling}systemFault; Fault Data is &a... Sending errors for the pending requests in the process scope before terminating the process instance
   Caused by: BPCOR-6131: An Error status was received while doing an invoke (partnerLink=externalBPELImplementation, portType={http://www.webservicex.net}CCCheckerSoap, operation=ValidateCardNumber)
BPCOR-6129: Line Number is 37
BPCOR-6130: Activity Name is Invoke1
   Caused by: HTTP Status-Code 404: Not Found - Not Found</detailText>
      </detail>
```

I've created a separated project to test the external WSDL and it is validating credit card numbers as expected, there's something wrong with my BPEL or my Composite Application.

If I create another test case and select the local port that is created when I drag and drop the Soap object into the Comp. App. Design interface, I get a different error:

```
Dec 24, 2012 12:54:11 AM com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection call
SEVERE: SAAJ0006: Bad URL (endPoint instance of String)
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @brasseld from www.open-esb.net

> In fact, you've made two mistake :
>
> - The first one, for your unit test, you have to use the good WSDL which come from the BPEL because you've created a concrete SOAP WSDL
>     (CreditCard_WSDL.wsdl).
> - Then, when you create a new port in your composite application for your plnk externalServiceCard_WSDL, you have to set the soap address
>     location by right-click > properties. By default, this one is set to
>     localhost:${HttpDefaultPort}/compositeapp/casaportX?wsdl that's why
>     you encounter your errors (404 or bad url error).

Based on his suggestions, I've decided to document the development process step-by-step, here's the result:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1W1xR3-iJQ

Answer (score 1):

Your process seams to be correct (at the first look).
It looks like your process can't find the service you ask:

BPCOR-6130: Activity Name is Invoke1 - Caused by: HTTP Status-Code 404: Not Found - Not Found

Is your "soap adress" in the wsdl you imported correct ?
Have you try to overload the url in the bpel mapping ? (Properties -> SOAP HTTP BC -> Outbound -> UR)

There is also something strnage in your CASA: If you are trying to consume "localCreditCard_WSDLPort" and expose in OpenESB "casaPort1", the SOAP Binding are inversed. The arrow should start from casaPort1 and finish at localCreditCard_WSDLPort.

I hope this could help you,

Simon

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've double checked the Soap Address in the external WSDL document, it is correct. Also, about my Composite Application Service Assembly, I can't connect the components the way you described. Do you have a working project that you can send me?

Comment: It fails right here... it can't find the Web Service for some reason, why? <invoke name="Invoke1" partnerLink="externalCreditCard_WSDL" operation="ValidateCardNumber" xmlns:tns="http://www.webservicex.net" portType="tns:CCCheckerSoap" inputVariable="ValidateCardNumberIn" outputVariable="ValidateCardNumberOut"/>